# Using Loops in C language, the loop shall terminate if the user inputs vowels and the number of the inputted characters already reached by 10

Tags: loops, do-loops

The output must print characters but separated by next line and the code must stop if the user already inputted 10 characters or if the user inputs a vowel.
[CODE HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CzFx.png)

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Yes.. But the loop only stops in vowels when i tried...when i try to input a consonant in the end, the loop errors

Comment: Please share a piece of code, where you think you are having errors/issue.

Comment: please click the hyperlink. Thank you!